# Call a Method in Activity Class from Another Class With its Context

Tags: java, android, android-activity, location, android-context

I'm trying to create a class for reading location and that it can be used for different activities in my android application. But nothing works.
I think the problem is when I try to call the method refresh activity.

Location Custom Class

```
public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {
    //Constantes
    private static final int LOCATION_MIN_TIME = 30 * 1000;
    private static final int LOCATION_MIN_DISTANCE = 10;
    /*Objetos de Inicialización*/
    private Actividad Actividad;
    private LocationManager Administrador;
    private Location Localizador;
    /*Objetos de Respuesta*/
    private Double Longitud;
    private Double Latitud;
    private Double Altitud;
    private String Metodo;

    public Localizacion(Context Contexto) {
        this.Actividad = (Actividad) Contexto;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Actividad.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Actividad.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //        ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                                                                  int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        this.Administrador.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 10, (LocationListener) this);
        onLocationChanged(this.Localizador);
    }

    private void ObtenerMetodo() {
        Context ContextoActual = Actividad.getApplicationContext();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ContextoActual, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ContextoActual, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //        ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                                                                  int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        this.Localizador = Administrador.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(this.Localizador == null) {
                this.Localizador = Administrador.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if(this.Localizador == null){
                    this.Metodo = "RED";
                }
                else {
                    this.Metodo = "N/A";
                }
            }
        else {
                    this.Metodo = "GPS";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(Localizador != null) {
            Longitud = location.getLongitude();
            Latitud = location.getLatitude();
            Altitud = location.getAltitude();
        }
        else
        {
            Longitud = null;
            Latitud = null;
            Altitud = null;
            ObtenerMetodo();
        }
    }

    public Double AltitudActual(){
        return Altitud;
    }
    public Double LatitudActual(){
        return Latitud;
    }
    public Double LongitudActual(){
        return Longitud;
    }
    public String MetodoActual(){
        return Metodo;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            ObtenerMetodo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            ObtenerMetodo();
    }
```

}

Activity Custom Class

```
public abstract class Actividad extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Actividad(){
        super();
    }
    public void Actualizar(){

    }
}
```

Activity App

```
public class ChooseSensor extends Actividad {

    Localizacion LocalizacionActual;
    FrameLayout Contenido;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_sensor);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Contenido = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_choose_sensor, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void Actualizar(){
        TextView textView = (TextView) Contenido.findViewById(R.id.texto);
        textView.setText("Metodo: "+LocalizacionActual.MetodoActual()+" Lon: "+LocalizacionActual.LongitudActual()+" Lat: "+LocalizacionActual.LatitudActual()+" Alt: "+LocalizacionActual.AltitudActual());
    }

    @Override
        protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LocalizacionActual = new Localizacion(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a Context variable named context, and in your Localizacion class constructor, do this.context = Contexto; instead of the one with Actividad

Comment: Look into using an EventBus or a LocalBroadcastReceiver instead of the above.

Comment: I resolved it with an interface.